# Is my pgsql database in recovery mode?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 8.4 database that I'm am trying to start in standby mode (I am shipping my own logs from the active DB).  I *think* my standby DB is in standby/recovery mode but I'm not sure how to tell.

First of all, pg_controldata says the database is "shut down":

```
[root@node2 pgsql]# pg_controldata data                                 
pg_control version number:            843
Catalog version number:               200904091
Database system identifier:           6514583873281163231
Database cluster state:               shut down
pg_control last modified:             Sun 15 Apr 2018 05:39:25 PM EDT
Latest checkpoint location:           7/56000020
Prior checkpoint location:            7/55000020
Latest checkpoint's REDO location:    7/56000020
Latest checkpoint's TimeLineID:       116
Latest checkpoint's NextXID:          0/40171
Latest checkpoint's NextOID:          20826
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiXactId:  1
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiOffset:  0
Time of latest checkpoint:            Sun 15 Apr 2018 05:39:24 PM EDT
Minimum recovery ending location:     0/0
Maximum data alignment:               8
Database block size:                  8192
Blocks per segment of large relation: 131072
WAL block size:                       8192
Bytes per WAL segment:                16777216
Maximum length of identifiers:        64
Maximum columns in an index:          32
Maximum size of a TOAST chunk:        1996
Date/time type storage:               64-bit integers
Float4 argument passing:              by value
Float8 argument passing:              by value
```

But that contradicts the status command output:

```
[root@node2 pgsql]# sudo -u postgres pg_ctl status -D /var/lib/pgsql/data  
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 35852)
/usr/bin/postgres "-D" "/var/lib/pgsql/data"
```

Yet when I try to start the database it says it's already running:

```
[root@node2 pgsql]# sudo -u postgres pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/pgsql/data   
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
[2018-04-15 23:06:11 GMT] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
[2018-04-15 23:06:11 GMT] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 35852) running in data directory "/var/lib/pgsql/data"?
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

And I can see that my recovery.conf is still in place:

```
[root@node2 pgsql]# cat data/recovery.conf 
restore_command='pg_standby -r 10 -t /var/run/myapp.trigger /var/lib/pgsql/data/myapp-archive "%f" "%p"'
```

And finally, I see an every growing list of files in the archive directory.

So, is there a way to tell if the wal (archive) files are being applied to the database?

Comment: Like I wrote on the mailing list, you should look into the log file and examine what the `pg_standby` process is doing.